# Cannot access a global final variable from within an inner class

Tags: android

I am using an animation to slide a view to the top of the screen. The code for the animation is contained within a method called `LoopAnimation()` which is called from main.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final View view = findViewById(R.id.view);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LoopAnimation(view); \\ The animation loop method

}
```

This `LoopAnimation()` method uses a nested `setOnClickListener` to create an animation loop

```
public void LoopAnimation(View view){
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starts the animation
            view.animate().translationY(-100);
            view.animate().setDuration(1500);

            // reverses the animation
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do some job here
                    view.animate().translationY(100);
                    view.animate().setDuration(1500);

                    LoopAnimation(view); // Method calls itself 
                                         // to create loop effect

                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that I am getting a trivial error that I can't understand. Although I have declared `view` as global and final, I get this error in `LoopAnimation()`

```
Variable 'view' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.
```

Comment: RogueBaneling answered your specific question.  You'll also find that `view` is null because you can't use `findViewById(...)` until after you've called `setContentView(...)`.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Thanks. So there 3 ways to do this (1) I make a global reference and reset the object it points to each time or (2) I create a new local variable every time with a new reference (3) use `this` key word?

Comment: None of the above.  Your reference isn't global and doesn't need to be.  It doesn't need to be `final`, either.  Remove the local variable (the method parameter) that hides the class member, and simply refer to the class member as `view`.

Comment: My bad. Looks like Java just can't change the value of a variable inside another method if that variable isn't global, unless Java is specifically using a constructor. Now If I remove the method parameter as you say, then I need I need to instantiate a new view object every time e.g. `View view = findViewById(R.id.view)` correct?

Comment: You're not instantiating the View, just getting a reference to it.  You only need to assign it once per activity instance, e.g., in `onCreate(...)`.  Honestly, your questions make very little sense, and I'm not sure if you're understanding my responses, because you seem to be wildly misusing terminology.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I see. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the variable `view` that is defined within your method's scope. Notice that your method's parameter is also called `view` so you are not actually using the global variable that you think you are using.

```
public void LoopAnimation(View view){
```

**Edit**: I've looked more into the way that you are trying to do this, and the approach isn't what I would do. Here is something more reasonable:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View view = findViewById(R.id.view);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private boolean _forwards = true;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (_forwards) {
                    // starts the animation
                    v.animate().translationY(-100);
                    v.animate().setDuration(1500);
                    _forwards = false;
                } else {
                    // reverses the animation
                    v.animate().translationY(100);
                    v.animate().setDuration(1500);
                    _forwards = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So what is the most efficient way to animate the view. Do I just need to make a new `view` object every time I call another method e.g. `View view = findViewById(R.id.view)`?

Comment: I updated my answer with a much cleaner approach to what it is that I think you are trying to achieve.